# Python operations on tensors without TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Here is my example from my code:

```
loss += lambda_coord * ((tf.math.sqrt(bb[2]) - tf.math.sqrt(label[2]))**2 
                                   + (tf.math.sqrt(bb[3]) - tf.math.sqrt(label[3]))**2)
```

bb is a tensor and so is label

Is it possible for me to rewrite this as

```
loss += lambda_coord * ((math.sqrt(bb[2]) - math.sqrt(label[2]))**2 
                                   + (math.sqrt(bb[3]) - math.sqrt(label[3]))**2)
```

using only the standard library function?

Another example, if I have a tensor which only contains the value 2, can I do 2 * tensor, or do I have to use the tf.math.multiply function?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @AMC I cannot since the other code is not working at the moment

Comment: You can try it separately, no?